# Number of binary trees with equal values

Tags: binary-tree

There is array of values:

1 - n_1 times

2 - n_2 times

...

k - n_k times

How many trees with this nodes exist?

I create simple algorythm:

```
int get_count(const vector<int> n_i) {
  if (n_i.size() <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    int total_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_i.size(); ++i) {
      vector<int> first;
      vector<int> second;
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        first.push_back(n_i[j]);
      }
      if (n_i[i] != 1) {
        second.push_back(n_i[i] - 1);
      }
      for (int j = i + 1; j < n_i.size(); ++j) {
        second.push_back(n_i[j]);
      }
      total_count += (get_count(first) * get_count(second));
    }
    return total_count;
  }
}
```

Because

#(n_1, n_2, ... n_k) = #(n_1 - 1, n_2, ..., n_k) + #(n_1) #(n_2 - 1, ... n_k) + ... + #(n_1, ..., n_k - 1)

and

#(0, n_i, n_j, ...) = #(n_i, n_j, ...)

But my code is so slow.

Is there a final formula via Cathalan's numbers, for example?

Comment: Is there any restriction on the tree, like sorting, balancing? If there is none then doesn't the question split into 1) how many permutations of ... are there and 2) how many different binary trees of size `sum(n_i)` are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem can be split into calculating the number of permutations and calculating the number of binary trees of given size. I converted my initial recursive Java code (which gives up on n1=10,n2=10,n3=10) into this iterative one:

```
static int LIMIT = 1000;

static BigInteger[] numberOfBinaryTreesOfSize = numberOfBinaryTreesBelow(LIMIT);
static BigInteger[] numberOfBinaryTreesBelow(int m) {
    BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[m];
    arr[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    arr[1] = arr[2] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int n = 3; n < m; n++) {
        BigInteger s = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            s = s.add(arr[i].multiply(arr[n - i]));
        arr[n] = s;
    }
    return arr;
}

static BigInteger[] fac = facBelow(LIMIT);
static BigInteger[] facBelow(int m) {
    BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[m];
    arr[0] = arr[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i < m; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1].multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    return arr;
}

static BigInteger getCountFast(int[] arr) {
    // s: sum of n_i
    int s = 0; for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { s += arr[i]; }
    // p: number of permutations
    BigInteger p = fac[s]; for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { p = p.divide(fac[arr[i]]); }
    BigInteger count = p.multiply(numberOfBinaryTreesOfSize[s]);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCountFast(new int[]{ 150, 150, 150, 150, 150 }));
}
```

The `LIMIT` limits the sum of the n_i. The above example takes about two seconds on my machine. Maybe it helps you with a C++ solution.